Apple programming-libraries & software: What's the meaning of the prefix "Core"?
Many Apple-libraries got this Prefix "Core", like for example "Core Location", "Core Data", "Core Graphics", "Core Storage".
What's the meaning of "Core ..."? Where does it come from?

Hi! What’s the problem you are solving here? Please note, asking why Apple does things is off topic and this reads as why did Apple choose this name. Could you edit this to show a practical problem you face given Apple has chosen to name things they way they did?

I don't think there's any particular meaning other than "fundamental" or "key".
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices
This page about Core Services talks about ".. Core Services framework, which encompasses many fundamental operating system services.... Access and manage key operating system services".
I suspect Apple may like using the adjective because:  Apple... core.
